# converting vanitygenplus into javascript

Tags: javascript, c, openssl

I'm currently working on converting vanitygenplus (https://github.com/exploitagency/vanitygen-plus) from C into JavaScript to run in a web-browser.
As I dont really know C ive been going almost line by line converting what I need and setting the rest to remarks for now. but now I reached this:

```
pkey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
```

Is this creating a random key or just creating a holder for the key, and what form would that be in?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Show (a relevant extract of) the code that contains the line and your equivalent JavaScript code. Add a reference to the original file. A quick search for the function name leads to e.g. https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name.html which states "*EC_KEY_new(), EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name() and EC_KEY_dup() return a pointer to the newly created EC_KEY object, or NULL on error.*" I dont know if there is an easy way to convert OpenSSL calls to JavaScript.

Comment: I guess short question would be is this generating a random 256 bit number and storing it in on object called pkey or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know the details and suggest to read the documentation of OpenSSL and check example code. The functions return a pointer to a type `EC_KEY` which is a `typedef struct ec_key_st EC_KEY;`. As far as I understood, this structure is an "object" which *can* hold a public and/or private key. You have to generate a key with a separate function call. See an example at https://rjordaney.is/code_exercises/ecdsa_openssl/